# Future Annotations in Trigger

Tags: trigger, future

**Is there Possible to use Future Annotations in Trigger then what is the Difference between Synchronous and Asynchronous trigger**

For Example Like this:

```
for (contact ce:Trigger.New)
{
@Future
------

}
```

**Possible or Not Please anyone Explain**

Comment: I wrote an answer a while back here of a pattern that I do, you should be able to re purpose it.. The answers below look spot on also http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131275/pass-listsobject-to-future/131283#131283

Answer (score 1):

First yes its possible.

Second if you do it you can easily hit the governer limit which is 50 future `callout` per transaction. Trigger run in batch of 200 and there may be more record in single transaction so you can easily hit the limit. So not a **recommend** approach

If you have to pass records pass the record Ids as a list and query the records again in the Future method

> Apex trigger

```
trigger contactTigger on contact(before update)
{
  util.callWebService(Trigger.newMap.keyset())
}
```

> Apex Class code

```
Public with sharing class util
{
   @Future(callout = true)
   public void static callWebService(Set<Id> contactIdSet)
   {
      //some code here
   }
}
```

[Reference](http://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/2014/10/30/invoke-future-methods-through-apex-trigger-for-web-service-callout/)

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_workbook.meta/integration_workbook/integration2a_5.htm)

Comment: Share some Example  for Webservice Callouts in Future annotations using Trigger

Comment: @user36188 check my updated code.

Comment: Image code, boo. That's not too much to type out!

Comment: To address the letter of the question, the `@future` annotation cannot be applied to the trigger itself. It must be applied to a specific method in an Apex class, and that Apex class can be called by the trigger. As mentioned, you must exercise greater care when calling/queuing asynchronous operations from triggers to avoid running into limits (or undesirable side effects)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call the future method from a trigger. You will have to take the limits in consideration when you do so.

Some best practice -

1. Don't call it in a for loop as it can easily hit the limit. Collect all the   values and pass it as a list.
2. If you have to pass records pass the record Ids as a list and query the records again in the Future method. As in asynchronous process the record might have changed when the process executes.